# API post call returns lots of addition text

Tags: rest-api, json

https://api.ivr-platform.com/api/token-auth

after submission this doesn't return just the json object but the entire webpage with a json object in the text.

```
public without sharing class OutreachStraticsToolkit {
    public static void getauthtoken()
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.ivr-platform.com/api/token-auth');
        req.setMethod('POST');        

        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     
        req.setBody('email=xxxxx&password=xxxxx');
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

    }

}
```

this returns current token and next token as null for both[image]

so my question is, whats the best way to parse this into a json object so that I can get the token out of the json object

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, it seems you are getting other values in the response. The earlier approach will only work if you have a valid JSON being deserialized. Salesforce will not be able to parse/deserialize if it's not a valid JSON. One of the approaches you can use here is to be able to utilize [`String.substring()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) to get the JSON part only from the response and then utilize the deserialize method. If you know from where your JSON starts within the response and that JSON is the last content within that response, you can have something as below to get the JSON and then utilize the approach below.

```
String jsonOnly = res.getBody().substringAfter(the string just before the JSON);
```

In all other cases, you will need to work with the API provider to understand how they are sending the response and how you can extract the required attributes from it.

Once you have extracted the JSON, you can then utilize [`JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) here. This will deserialize your response in a `Map` where the key will be the attribute name and its corresponding value as value in the map. You can then utilize whatever attribute you want from the JSON response.

E.g., to get only the token, you will need something as below.

```
Map<String, Object> responseMap = 
    (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonOnly);

String token = (String) responseMap.get('token');

// ignore or process other values
```

Comment: This does not work, Line: 11, Column: 1
System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [4,2]

Comment: With this information it just seems that your JSON is not well formatted. If your JSON *complies* to the JSON format, then this should definitely work. It's difficult to say how your JSON looks like with this level of information

Comment: in the first line of my question i state "after submission this doesn't return just the json object but the entire webpage with a json object in the text." please tell me what additional infromation you requrie

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to work with your API provider in this case as what response to expect. If you want to deserialize a JSON response, Salesforce expects it to be a *strict* JSON. You cannot either create a parser or deserialize the response in current form if its not a JSON. In your case you will first need to extract the JSON part of the response and then utilize the approach here. I will update my answer with that approach, if that helps. In all other cases you will need to work with the API provider to understand their response model.

Answer (score 0):

Look into JSON.deserialize instead of JSON.createParser.  It will allow you to push your JSON string into an object that you define.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm

Comment: Will this truncate all the additional text besides the json object? or will I be at the same roadblock i am currently at, if so, does this really solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: This answer landed in one of the review queues. I think this one would be improved if you provided a simple example of a class used for deserialization + how to use it with `JSON.deserialize()` (for when the links eventually go dead).